# How to stop child controls layout updates during animation of parent size

Tags: wpf

I've created a "flyout" effect by creating a narrow `Border` control down the side of my window. When the mouse moves over the control I trigger a storyboard that increases its width to reveal it fully.

The problem is, as the border is increasing in size you see the layout of the child controls being constantly updated. Is there any way to prevent this until the animation has completed?

Comment: What about a `DataTrigger` on the inner controls that hides them unless the `ActualWidth` is equal to its maximum size?